# get the regex match result only upto the first occurance

Tags: regex

I want to use a regex to find only upto first specific character match

eg :
string :

```
<!ENTITY GET    '<command xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">GET</command>'>
```

i want output as matched result

```
ENTITY GET    '
```

Currently i am using regex

```
ENTITY\ [\&,\%]?.*\'
```

which results into (not desired)

```
ENTITY GET    '<command xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">GET</command>'
```

Any improved regex for my goal?

EDIT : Please also let me know what is wrong with my regex?

PS : My end goal is to find the entity name that is 'GET' in this case by using some regex. Based on the XML standard of finding ENTITY NAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options here:

- Use `?` after `*` (turn the *greedy* qualifier `*` into a *non-greedy* or *minimal* qualifier): `.*?'`
- Replace `.` with `[^']` (instead of "match any char", "match any char but `'`"): `[^']*'`